# MDM server setup

Tags: ios, ios4, mdm

I am trying to develop an enterprise application which needs  to list all the installed applications in iphone and to delete some selected applications in device from my application.I found that this is possible only by using MDM server.I searched a lot for an exact document regarding this.It would be great if anyine clarify my following doubts :

1 .Steps and Configurations to follow an MDM server and make the server communicate with device

2 .Steps to do on the client side

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deleting applications is not possible, even with using MDM.  See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516857/documents-for-mdm-integration-in-iphone

Comment: An application can be removed if it was managed/pushed by the MDM in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure your MDM server you need to follow the below steps

1.You need to enroll in iOS Developer Enterprise Pragramm.

2.Try to get a signed Certificate Signing Request (CSR) from your MDM vendor .

3.Once you have a signed CSR from your vendor, visit identity.apple.com/pushcert and sign in with a verified Apple ID.

4.Click "Create a Certificate” and agree to the Terms of Use.

5.Select your signed CSR and click upload. After a moment, your certificate will be available for download.

6.This certificate can now be uploaded to your MDM server for use with the Apple Push Notification service.

7.In your MDM Server you need to implement your Profile Manager ,implement your Push server add the SCEP stack.

In MDM capabilities there is remote wipe feature,so you can wipe out the device data remotely.
You can list out all the MDM capabilities in [this PDF](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_MDM.pdf) and refer [this](http://iosmdm.blogspot.in).

Comment: I completed successfully till step 6. But the generated push certificate (when viewed in keychain store) says "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". There's also no private key associated with it. Help will be appreciated..

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502420/the-identity-certificate-for-com-xyz-profile-mdm-could-not-be-found and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293363/how-to-set-mdm-payloads-identity-in-ipcu

Comment: I'm using Mac and have followed softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning followed by stackoverflow.com/a/9756116/864850 to merge the public/private keys. But still I don't get the private key with the Push certificate in the keychain. Any idea where I could be wrong?