# Documents for MDM Integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm

Can any one help me out how to do MDM Integration in iPhone from client prespective without using APN. Because I want to do an enterprise application which need to list all the installed apps in iPhone and also should allow the user to delete some apps from current application.

Comment: How do you get list of installed apps in iPhone ?

Answer (score 9):

1. You need to have an enterprise developer account to get the documents. If you can't get an enterprise account, you can't get the documents.
2. Apple has only given the iOS MDM documents to a select few enterprise developers around the world. You won't get access to them unless you can prove to Apple your business is in the field of Device Management and/or Mobility.
3. MDM uses apns. You have to use apns.
4. You can't get an application list without MDM.
5. You can't delete applications from inside an app.
6. You're not going to get the documents from Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. My requirements is i want to do an enterprise application which i need to list all the installed apps in iphone and also should allow the user to delete some apps from current application. So i think i cant use APN service because i want to do it from client prespective. My client have an enterprise account then how will the get mdm documents . One more doubt they need to pay for apple to get this and what is the pay..

Comment: No app on the iPhone can access any of the MDM queries or commands, and you can not remove apps from the device at all, using MDM or not.  Also, your client will be unable to get the MDM documentation unless they are a MDM provider.