# The identity certificate for com.xyz.profile.mdm could not be found?

Tags: iphone, ios, ota, mdm

I've bumped into this issue while trying to install a MDM profile onto an ipad as the final part of OTA enrollment.

```
NSError:
Desc   : The identity certificate for com.xyz.profile.mdm1 could not be found.
US Desc: The identity certificate for com.xyz.profile.mdm1 could not be found.
Domain : MCMDMErrorDomain
Code   : 12005
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
"com.xyz.profile.mdm1"
)
```

Anyone have idea what piece of information i'm missing?
This is when I try to install a MDM payload onto the IOS device after its completed the SCEP registration.

this is the payload I'm sending

```
<dict>
  <key>AccessRights</key>
  <integer>2047</integer>
  <key>CheckOutWhenRemoved</key>
  <true/>
  <key>IdentityCertificateUUID</key>
  <string>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</string>
  <key>PayloadDescription</key>
  <string>Configures MobileDeviceManagement.</string>
  <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.xyz.profile.mdm</string>
  <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
  <string></string>
  <key>PayloadType</key>
  <string>com.apple.mdm</string>
  <key>PayloadUUID</key>
  <string>3DF45C81-F1C4-4427-A61D-0581D9303214</string>
  <key>PayloadVersion</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
  <key>ServerURL</key>
  <string>https://mymachine:2345/profile</string>
  <key>SignMessage</key>
  <false/>
  <key>Topic</key>
  <string>com.apple.mgmt.xyz</string>
  <key>UseDevelopmentAPNS</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send an identity certificate with the payload for the device to accept the profile. The PayloadUUID of this certificate needs to be set as the value of the IdentityCertificateUUID in the MDM dict.

Try creating a profile with the iPCU to check the format of the Credential block.

Comment: Do you know what this UUID should be if the device has previously gotten a certificate via the SCEP protocol? (in my case it has contacted the microsoft NDES server and has gotten a cert). Do I need to load another certificate on to the device? Or is it possible to refer to the SCEP cert somehow? At the point I'm generating the MDM payload, the device has sendt up the request signed with the cert it has gotten from the NDES server. I have access to the public thumbprint only.

Comment: I very much doubt it's possible to refer to the SCEP cert. The idea behind this cert is to sign the MDM responses from the device (if this is enabled), so the cert needs to be something you have access to on the server to check whether the responses are valid. However, even if you aren't signing the MDM responses, you still have to have an identity cert.

Comment: I found it is possible if the MDM profile is delivered with the SCEP profile.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! I've never done MDM with SCEP, only 'old style' profiles so that's great to know. Thanks.

Comment: @user526498, Could you, please, share more detailed explanation of how you combine SCEP and MDM payload in the same profile? I'm struggling with the same issue now. Thanks

Comment: Hey Maksym, you can download a copy of the iphone configuration utility free from apple.  Create a new profile with SCEP and MDM sections filled out, save it to disk as an unencrypted policy, open it up with notepad.  You can now use that to know the structure it needs to be in.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using self-signed ssl then,While generating self-signed ssl certificate in server side,generate identity.p12 certificate and this certificate you need to use in identity section of IPCU.

These few lines you can use to generate the idendtity.p12

```
//Creating the device Identity key and certificate request

openssl genrsa 2048 > identity.key
openssl req -new -key identity.key -out identity.csr


//Signing the identity key with the CA. 
//Give it a passphrase. You'll need to include that in the IPCU profile.

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in identity.csr -CA cacert.crt -CAkey cakey.key -CAcreateserial -out identity.crt

openssl pkcs12 -export -out identity.p12 -inkey identity.key -in identity.crt -certfile cacert.crt
```

Comment: I have successfully created Identity Key and request.But I am unable to Sign in the identity with the CA.I am getting the issue."9374:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fo‌​pen('cacert.crt','r') 9374:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358: unable to load certificate".Can you please suggest whats wrong