# Configuration Profile with MDM Payload not getting installed to the device

Tags: ios, configuration, profile, mdm, payload

Did anybody can tell me what's the reason for that Configuration Profile with MDM Payload not getting installed using IPCU.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps a bit old but your MDM server url must be a valid HTTPS URL with a cert from a trusted source, self signed certs will not work.

Comment: I generated push certificate for MDM. Its got a valid subject/topic. When viewed in keychain store it says "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". There's also no private key associated with it. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

View the console for the device in iPCU. This may help you to track down the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed ssl will work and while generating self-signed ssl certificate in server side,generate identity.p12 certificate and this certificate you need to use in identity section of IPCU and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502420/the-identity-certificate-for-com-xyz-profile-mdm-could-not-be-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068429/mdm-ssl-issue-for-server-url/10629311#10629311) also.

Please verify again.