# MDM: ssl issue for server url

Tags: ios, https, localhost, mdm

I want to manage the iOS devices using Lion Server,I have purchased the Lion Server and installed in Mac system which has Lion OS 10.7.
I want to manage the devices with in our own network, I have not taken domain specific for MDM.
While creating cofig profile for MDM in IPCU,it needs the server url must begin with "https://".

So I am not able to install the MDM config profile in the iOS device, due to "htts".I tried to get ssl certificate for trial , but that is not available for private networks.

Is there any solution to resolve the issue with out purchasing ssl certificate or public domain.

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong and suggest the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-signed ssl will work and while generating self-signed ssl certificate in server side,generate identity.p12 certificate and this certificate you need to use in identity section of IPCU.

And go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502420/the-identity-certificate-for-com-xyz-profile-mdm-could-not-be-found/10569613#10569613) also.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit a page on the MDM web server with Safari and get the pop-up dialog warning about the identity of the server then you will need to install the SSL certificate on the device to allow the certificate to be trusted. This can be achieved by using iPCU or allowing the certificate from a web server.